# c# equivalent of c++ callback

Tags: c#, c++14

I want to create a c# callback code where user send their own functions to be executed.
I am new to c# so I cant find a proper way to do this.
The equivalent c++ code is

```
class Test
{
    bool (*signin)(int);
    bool (*signout)();
public:
    void Register(bool(*usignin)(int), bool(*usignout)())
    {
        signin = usignin;
        signout = usignout;
    }
    void display(int a,int b)
    {
        signin(a + b);
        signout();
    }
};
```

Main function:

```
bool signin(int i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    return true;
}
bool signout()
{
    cout << "Signed out" << endl;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    Test *obj = new Test();
    obj->Register(signin, signout);
    obj->display(4,6);
}
```

In the main function the user is defining their own sign in and sign out and sending it through the register function. How can this be done in c#?

Comment: Study [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A usual way to do this in modern C# would be to define arguments as `Action<>` (no return type, `void`) or `Func<>` (with a return type), and pass lambdas or plain function when called.

So the corresponding signature of Register in your case seem to be this :

```
void Register(Func<int, bool> signin, Func<bool> signout)
```

and call it the same way you do in c++, by passing the name of defined functions in your code, or directly with lambdas :

```
Register((int id) => { Console.WriteLine($"logged in user with id {id}!"; return true; }, () => { Console.WriteLine("Sign out callback called."); return true; });
```

Note : the `int` should be optional in the lambda here.

Comment: So can you tell me how do I use the registered function inside the display function.

Comment: How do I use the registered function in display function

Comment: you can use the same pattern : define fields in your class, with same type of constructor parameters. Assign the fields in the constructor (and of course, null-check them if you wish). Then call them as you would call a function, as it is done in the C++ version. The code of the `Display` function would be exactly the same, if you keep same names for fields!

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want the same implementation exactly or you want a notification type of mechanism.

I would suggest to look for the best solution in each language. For example in C# you can use EventHandler, delegates or implement for example the observer pattern.

EventHandler: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/delegates-and-eventhandler-for-events-in-c-sharp

observer pattern: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/csharp/example

Comment: Care for the downvote? (atleast put a comment why you don't agree)